# All points where line tangent to circle

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm given that the circle has the equation $x^2+y^2=1$. There is a line through $(5,0)$ and $(x,y)$. How do you find all $x,y$ such that the line is tangent to the circle? $(x,y)$ is on the circle.

Comment: How many tangents are there to a circle from a point outside it?

Comment: Doesn't give how many tangents. Just says to find all points that make the line tangent.

Comment: I'm trying to get you to think about the situation - draw a diagram, and then you will know what kind of answer to expect. You may also see how geometrical methods can be used - as well as algebraic ones using the equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic tangent line to the unit circle $S^1$ through the point $(a,b) \in S^1$ has equation $a(x-a) + b(y-b) = 0.$ Since you want this line to go through $(5,0),$ we must have $a(5 - a) - b^2 = 0,$ i.e., $-(a^2 + b^2) + 5a = 0.$ But $a^2 + b^2 = 1,$ so $a = 1/5$ and $b = \pm2\sqrt{6}/5.$

Answer (score 0):

1) If the line is tangent then the triangle $OAB$ is right, where $O=(0,0)$, $A=(x,y)$ and $B=(5,0)$.

2) Since the circle is unit, the coordinates of $A$ are $\cos\angle AOB$, $\pm\sin\angle AOB$.

3) You know $|OB|=5$ and $|OA|=1$, so that $|AB|=2\sqrt{6}$.

So, that the coordinates are $(\cos\angle AOB, \pm\sin\angle AOB)=(\frac{|OA|}{|OB|}, \pm\frac{|AB|}{|OB|})$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the points $(x_1,y_1)$ on the circle that satisfy the relationship we find the slope $\frac{y_1-0}{x_1-5}$, which also equals the derivative of the circle at that point, $\frac{-x_1}{y_1}$. Together with $x_1^2+y_1^2=1$ you can algebraically find the points.